# Selecting same item in 2 different Grid-Views

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

I have 2 RadGridView. 
GridView 1: short list has items from GridView2.
GridView 2: Long list has telerik:RadGridView.GroupDescriptors for group the items.

I want if I select one row in first GridView takes me to the same Row in the second GridView. 
So, I put in Xaml

```
//XAML
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDP}" For GridView1
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDP1}" For GridView2
//CS
        private DataPermission mSelectedDP = new DataPermission();
        public DataPermission SelectedDP
        {
            get { return mSelectedDP; }
            set
            {
                mSelectedDP = value;

                    foreach (SecurityDataPermissions m in DisplayedDataPermissionsList)
                {
                    if (m.DataPermission.DataPointName == SelectedDP.DataPointName)
                        SelectedDP1 = m;
                }

                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDP");
            }
        }

        private SecurityDataPermissions mSelectedDP1 = new SecurityDataPermissions();
        public SecurityDataPermissions SelectedDP1 
        {
            get { return mSelectedDP1; }
            set
            {
                this.mSelectedDP1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDP1");
            }
        }
```

The row in GridView2 is getting selected but it doesn't scroll to it. I mean if manually scrolled to the item I can see it gray (selected but not focused) but If not, I can't recognize which row is selected.
What I want is when I select row in GridView1 takes me to the same row in GridView2

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the `SelectionChanged` event and call the `ScrollIntoViewAsync` method in the event handler as suggested in the [official documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/columns/how-to/scroll-item#scrollintoviewasync).

```
private void gridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, Telerik.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangeEventArgs e)
{
    gridView.ScrollIntoViewAsync(gridView.SelectedItem, radgridView.Columns[0]);
}
```

You may of course wrap this functionality in an attached behaviour if you want to: https://www.telerik.com/forums/auto-scroll-to-the-selected-item